# Calling unstated function using componentDidMount or from another file

Tags: reactjs, react-context, unstated

I am trying to create a context to store all the info needed for my app, the code below works but I do have limitations, this is `Api.js` where I want to put all the logic and API requests/responses.

```
import { Provider, Subscribe, Container } from "unstated";
import fire from "./config/Fire";

class APIContainer extends Container {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      loading: null,
    };
  }
  async auth() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true, loading: false });
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false, loading: false });
      }
    });
  }
}

const Api = {
  Instance: new APIContainer(),
  Provider,
  Subscribe
};

export default Api;
```

> This App.js `<Routes />`  is a basic react router with few paths

```
 <Api.Provider inject={[Api.Instance]}>
    <Routes />
 </Api.Provider>
```

On components I can use the context but only in render method like so :

```
<Api.Subscribe to={[Api.Instance]}>
{api => (
   <p>String(api.state.loggedIn)</p>
   <button onClick={() => api.auth()}>run</button>
  )}
 </Api.Subscribe>
```

Now my goal is to either implement a `componentDidMount` in the `APIContainer` or access the function on any component, I tried with props didn't worked!

```
componentDidMount = () => {
 this.props.api.auth();
}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code, the `api.auth()` just valid inside Subscribe, it is invalid at `componentDidMount`.

If you want to auto-auth at `componentDidMount`, you should make a child component, and pass `auth()` to it.

I made an example for you. 
You can see that you want on the console.

[a unstated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v843w68wly?fontsize=14)